# React Native crashes in AppStore builds

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, app-store

It's my first time working on a React Native project. Everything works fine on the Android build Im able to make release builds and push to PlayStore. However for iOS I can run release build on both emulator and on my physical device from XCode but when I archive and push it to AppStore and download it from there the app crashes immediately after I start it. It shows the splash screen for less than a second then crashes.

[Below is the report I get from AppStore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahAwt.jpg)

I have wrapped the app in sentry at the root of the project but it crashes so early that Sentry doesnt catch the error.

Comment: Those native bugs are really annoying. You can try hooking your phone up to Xcode and checking the logs on your phone as it crashes. the log should start with "*** Terminating..." When it happened to me it was just some dependencies I needed to install even though it worked on expoGo simulator.